# Nextjs not sending csrf token to my django server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, next.js, cookies

My code is working on localhost and I can see csrf by console log

[image]

but when deploy on my server https I don't see csrf token and it's null I don't know why

[image]

I am struggling to solve this problems from past few days and still now don't have any solution. I am not understanding why it's not working on production when deploy on my server but same code working on localhost. here is my react code for axois post

```
 const handleClickComment =  (main_comment_id)=>{
   
  const csrfToken =  cookies.get("csrftoken")
   axios.post(url,comment_data,{
      withCredentials:true,
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken, // Adding the CSRF token to the request headers
      },
```

my django settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by email
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
     
]


CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://*",
    "https://*",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "https://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "https://127.0.0.1:3000",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://*',
    "https://*", 
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "https://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "https://127.0.0.1:3000",
]


CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    
         'http://*',
         "https://*",
         "http://localhost:3000",
         "https://localhost:3000",
         "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
         "https://127.0.0.1:3000",
         
                                            
                         
                        ]
 
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True




CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + (
    'xsrfheadername',
    'xsrfcookiename',
    'content-type',
    'x-csrftoken',
)


CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False  # False since we will grab it via universal-cookies
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

I am using django rest API. here is my api function which I warped with @csrf_exempt

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["GET","POST","PUT","DELETE"])
def CommentAPI(request, slug):
```